# Message 'pagebreakavoidchecked="true";' showed on new page

Tags: mpdf

Till now, we are generating correctly PDFs with mPDF, combining PHP + CSS `@page`, that includes "page-break-before" and "page-break-after" . We write each block using "writeHTML" class. However, after some changes, we noticed that mPDF generates and display the message `pagebreakavoidchecked="true";` and the top of the page after page break after summary, just when we began to put headers and footers.

We have no idea why is that message appearing just and only at that page.

Please, any idea? Do you need any other info?

Thank you

Update: I discovered mPDF have some problem with "page-break-inside: avoid;". I'm using it this way:

HTML:

```
<article class="bloque_anuncio">
    <header class="cabecera_anuncio"> 
        <p class="nivel1">Level 1</p>
        <p class="nivel2">Level 2</p>
        <p class="nivel3">Level 3</p>
        <p class="nivel4">Level 4</p>
    </header>
    <div class="contenido_anuncio">
        a lot of text (at least a complete page, but usually several pages)
    </div>
</article>
```

There are several articles, but I want to maintain header aside with the content, so I use in my stylesheet:
    .cabecera_anuncio {page-break-inside: avoid; }

And it works as it should, however, mPDF inserts the mentioned message at the beginning of the first page (and only there):
[image: This is a capture of the text inserted by mPDF in the first page (not of the document, but the first time it should use the style]
If I remove the style, the message dissapear, but I need to avoid page breaks in that point!!

Comment: Sharing a screenshot of what's being generated as well as a small code sample to replicate the issue would be helpful.

Comment: Can't add all HTML content, cause it has a lot of pages, but that's the basic content: A (PHP created) summary + (CSS generated with page-break-after:always;) pagebreak + article + article + article + article + .....

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the problem is only relative to the `<p>` tag. Try to substitute with a `<div>` tag

Comment: Problem was not related with tags. Finally we changed the way we used the page break as a workaround and the message dissapeared. Thank you anyway!